# Google Analytics does not show original referrer

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have the same tracking code on my main site and on a subdomain.

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-26266386-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I now have a lot of traffic directly to my subdomain. but google analytics does not show the original referrer. it shows the subdomain itself as the referrer... how can i change that? do i need to use a seperat tracking id?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your subdomains to the Referral Exclusion list: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en

Comment: thanks @nyuen, I already tryed that. but the original source will still not be displayed...

Comment: Can you share examples of the kinds of scenarios you are seeing where subdomain shows up as a referrer? Thanks! Also, just make sure your tracking code is on ALL pages of your subdomain.

Comment: oh never mind. the crazy traffic was generated through a newsletter... but thanks for your help!